# View image automatically after being saved in local-storage

Tags: android, android-studio

How can the image be shown automatically after being saved in storage. It should be displayed using built in image viewer.

**Code**

```
 if(success) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:" + image+"/Rabta/"+random+".png"), "image/png");
     startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show the image this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:" + "/path/to/image"), "image/png");
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: kindly see the code i have posted..

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: yes it's showing me the error 'couldn't find item'

Comment: Please, post the stacktrace.

Comment: got the answer.. Thankyou for the help.